# Reading RC channels from mega 2560

Tags: arduino, rc

I'm trying to read signals from fs-ct6b using Mega 2560 with this code:

```
int val;
int ch_in[6] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int ch_out[6] = {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    pinMode(ch_in[i], INPUT);
    pinMode(ch_out[i], OUTPUT);
  }
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    val = pulseIn(ch_in[i], HIGH);
    Serial.print("Ch #");
    Serial.print(i + 1, DEC);
    Serial.print(" = ");
    Serial.println(val, DEC);
  };

  Serial.println("\n");
  delay(100); 
}
```

but the received values are grater by 300-400 than I expect. For example throttle values changes between 1418 and 2442, but the same RC connected to my quad in Mission Planner\multiwii GUI gives ~1100 - 1950. What is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of pulseIn() works fine:

```
ulong pulseIn(int pin, int timeout){
  ulong uStart, uEnd, _timer, _pass;
  _timer = micros();
  while (HIGH == digitalRead(pin)){
    _pass = micros() - _timer;
    if (_pass > TIME_OUT)
      return 0;
  };

  while (LOW == digitalRead(pin)){
    _pass = micros() - _timer;
    if (_pass > TIME_OUT)
      return 0;
  };
  uStart = micros();  
  while (HIGH == digitalRead(pin)){
    _pass = micros() - _timer;
    if (_pass > TIME_OUT)
      return 0;
  };
  uEnd = micros();
  return uEnd - uStart;
}
```

The other way is to use interrupts as shown here:

http://rcarduino.blogspot.ru/2012/01/how-to-read-rc-receiver-with.html

UPD. The problem was in Arduino IDE version installed by package manager. The "original" version from arduino.cc works fine.